# use regex with array_diff() to exclude files with given extension

Tags: php, regex

I echo out a directory's contents, excluding some files like this:

```
$exclude_list = array(".", "..", "index.php",".htaccess");
$scanned_directory = array_diff(scandir($dir), $exclude_list);
```

I would like to add all the files in the directory with the extension `.meta.js` to the exclude list. Can I do that with a regex, or would I have to loop through them and add them to the array individually, or is there some other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/preg_grep) with a regex would be suitable to filter your list.

```
 preg_grep("/^(\.|\.\.|index\.php|\.htaccess)$|\.meta\.js$/",
     $scanned_dirs, PREG_GREP_INVERT)
```

This covers your existing excludes, as well as the meta extension.